# Which MySQL Query is faster?

Tags: mysql, database

Which query will execute faster and which is perfect query ?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    students
WHERE
    status = 1
AND
    classes_id IN(
                    SELECT
                        id
                    FROM
                        classes
                    WHERE
                        departments_id = 1
                );
```

Or

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    students s
LEFT JOIN
    classes c
ON
    c.id = s.classes_id
WHERE
    status = 1
AND
    c.departments_id = 1
```

I have placed two queries both will output same result. Now I want to know which method will execute faster and which method is correct way ?

Comment: Which was faster when you tested it?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to run both and see for yourself. Example: `explain select count(*) ...`

Comment: EXPLAIN both you will get the answer

Comment: @eggyal: interesting, however not the same subject.

Comment: Your table structure is strange. Why does a student have a "classes_id"? How will you represent a student attending more than one class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use `EXPLAIN` to determine how your query will run.

Unfortunately, MySQL will execute your subquery as a DEPENDENT QUERY, which means that the subquery will be ran for each row in the outer query. You'd think MySQL would be smart enough to detect that the subquery isn't a correlated subquery and would run it just once, alas, it's not yet that smart.

So, MySQL will scan through all of the rows in students, running the subquery for each row, and not utilizing any indexes on the outer query whatsoever.

Writing the query as a JOIN would allow MySQL to utilize indexes, and the following query would be the optimum way to write it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROMstudents s
JOIN classes c
  ON c.id = s.classes_id
  AND c.departments_id = 1
WHERE s.status = 1
```

This would utilize the following indexes:

```
students(`status`)
classes(`id`, `departements_id`) : multi-column index
```

Answer (score 3):

From a design and clarity standpoint I'd avoid inner selects like the first one.  It is true that to be 100% sure on if or how each query will be optimized and which will run 'better' requires seeing how the SQL server you're using will interperet it and its plan.  In Mysql, use "Explain".

However.... Even without seeing this, my money is still on the Join only version...  The inner select version has to perform the inner select in it's entirety before determining the values to use inside the "IN" clause--I know this to be true when you wrap stuff in functions, and pretty sure it's true when sticking a select in as IN arguements.  I also know that that's a good way to totally neutralize any benefit you might have with indexes on the tables inside the inner select.

I'm generally of the opinion that Inner selects are only really needed for very rare query situations.  Usually, those who use them often are thinking like traditional iterative flow programmers not really thinking in relational DB result set terms...

Answer (score 2):

**EXPLAIN** Both the queries individually

The difference between both queries is of Sub-Queries vs Joins

Mostly Joins are faster than sub-queries. Join creates execution plan and predict what data is going to process, hence it saves time. On the other hand sub-queries run all the queries until all the data is loaded. Most developer use Sub-queries because these are more readable than JOINS, but where the performance is matter, JOIN is better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out is to measure it:

**Without index**

- Query 1: 0.9s
- Query 2: 0.9s

**With index**

- Query 1: 0.4s
- Query 2: 0.2s

The conclusion is:

- If you don't have indexes then it makes no difference which query you use.
- The join is faster if you have the right index.
- The effect of adding the correct index is greater than the effect of choosing the right query. If performance matters, make sure you have the correct indexes.

Of course, your results may vary depending on the MySQL version and the distribution of data you have.

Here's how I tested it:

- 1,000,000 students (25% with status 1).
- 50,000 courses.
- 10 departments.

Here's the SQL I used to create the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
status int NOT NULL,
classes_id int NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE classes
(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
departments_id INT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE numbers(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);

INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),();

INSERT INTO numbers
SELECT NULL
FROM numbers AS n1
CROSS JOIN numbers AS n2
CROSS JOIN numbers AS n3
CROSS JOIN numbers AS n4
CROSS JOIN numbers AS n5
CROSS JOIN numbers AS n6;

INSERT INTO classes (departments_id)
SELECT id % 10 FROM numbers WHERE id <= 50000;

INSERT INTO students (status, classes_id)
SELECT id % 4 = 0, id % 50000 + 1 FROM numbers WHERE id <= 1000000;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM students
WHERE status = 1
AND classes_id IN (SELECT id FROM classes WHERE departments_id = 1);

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN classes c
ON c.id = s.classes_id
WHERE status = 1
AND c.departments_id = 1;

CREATE INDEX ix_students ON students(status, classes_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

The two queries won't produce the same results:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    students
WHERE
    status = 1
AND
    classes_id IN(
                    SELECT
                        id
                    FROM
                        classes
                    WHERE
                        departments_id = 1
                );
```

...will return the number of rows in the students table that have a classes_id field that is also in the classes table with a departments_id of 1.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    students s
LEFT JOIN
    classes c
ON
    c.id = s.classes_id
WHERE
    status = 1
AND
    c.departments_id = 1
```

...will return the total number of rows in the students table where the status field is 1 and possibly more than that depending on how your data is organised.

If you want the queries to return the same thing, you need to change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN so it will match only the rows that suit both conditions.

Comment: This is correct. It happens that the two queries will return the same results in the OP's situation, because I assume all `students.classes_id` reference `classes.id`. But in the general case, the two queries are not sematically identical, therefore MySQL cannot optimze them in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on both queries and check which one does what ;)