# LEFT OUTER JOIN vs SUBSELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I have a table say `table1` which has 3 columns `column1, column2 and column3`.

The `column1` and `column2` are a `FOREIGN KEY` with 2 other tables. However the data in `column3` is from n number of tables.

For e.g. Let us consider Facebook. To display the activities it might maintain a table which could have `user1 photoliked photo1` or `user1 statusliked status1`.  So in this case `column3` cannot be a `FOREIGN KEY` with a specific table.

Now there are 2 ways of getting real data -

1st way -

```
SELECT user_id,
       verb_id,
       CASE WHEN verb_id = photoliked THEN
            (SELECT photo_name FROM photos WHERE photo_id = column3) -- getting the desired data from the third column
         WHEN verb_id = statusliked THEN
            (SELECT status FROM statustable WHERE status_id = column3) 
         ELSE '' END AS performedon
FROM table1
     JOIN table2 ON user_id = user_id  -- joining the first column
     JOIN table3 ON verb_id = verb_id  -- joining the second column
```

2nd way -

```
SELECT user_id,
       verb_id,
       CASE WHEN verb_id = photoliked THEN
            p.photo_name
         WHEN verb_id = statusliked THEN
            s.status
         ELSE '' END AS performedon
FROM table1
     JOIN table2 ON user_id = user_id  -- joining the first column
     JOIN table3 ON verb_id = verb_id  -- joining the second column
     LEFT JOIN photos p ON p.photo_id = column3  -- joining the column3 with specific table 
     LEFT JOIN statustable s ON s.status_id = column3
```

**Question**

Which of the 2 ways is better to retrieve data? 
and which of the 2 queries is less expensive?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/10684539/1239506

Comment: No it is not duplicate. In that question there is a `IN` in the `WHERE` clause and the `SUBSELECT` does not depend on any column of the main query.

Comment: The second query is better...

Comment: Could do an explain to analyze the query.

Comment: The second query is better , optimized , independant and faster. While the first query is dependant and takes more execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second would be faster and the reason is the first one contains what is called correlated subqueries. The subqueries have a correlation with records from the master query. So the subqueries need to be run once for every matching record in the master query. In your case it can't run the subquery until it determines the value of verb_id in the master query. That is a lot of queries to run.

An EXPLAIN on the first query should indicate this issue. It's is usually a red flag when you see that in an EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 1):

I think `JOIN` will be faster as it is performed once for a query, and also I would try to filter `verb_id` in `JOIN`

```
SELECT user_id,
   verb_id,
   COALESCE(p.photo_name, s.status) AS performedon
FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON user_id = user_id  -- joining the first column
    JOIN table3 ON verb_id = verb_id  -- joining the second column
    LEFT JOIN photos p ON verb_id = 'photoliked' AND p.photo_id = column3  -- joining the column3 with specific table 
    LEFT JOIN statustable s ON verb_id = 'statusliked' AND s.status_id = column3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach:

```
SELECT t.user_id,
       t.verb_id,
       p.photo_name  AS performedon
FROM table1 AS t
     JOIN table2 AS t2  ON t2.user_id = t.user_id  
     JOIN table3 AS t3  ON t3.verb_id = t.verb_id 
     JOIN photos AS p  ON  p.photo_id = t.column3  
                       AND t.verb_id = 'photoliked'

UNION ALL

SELECT t.user_id,
       t.verb_id,
       s.status  
FROM table1 AS t
     JOIN table2 AS t2  ON t2.user_id = t.user_id
     JOIN table3 AS t3  ON t3.verb_id = t.verb_id
     JOIN statustable AS s  ON  s.status_id = t.column3
                            AND t.verb_id = 'statusliked' ;
```